# Waitforseconds is skipping over

Tags: unity, c#

I have a function for a timer using waitforseconds but instead of waiting for how long I want to, it just skips it.

A ui text should become "foo" then 5 seconds later become "bar" but it turns to bar as soon as it starts.

Code:

```
void Update () {
     text1.text = "foo";
     wait (5);
     text1.text = "bar";
 }

 IEnumerator wait(int time)
 {
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
 }
```

Comment: I don't know syntax off top of my head, but throw the "bar" line into the Wait method after the wait line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [StartCoroutine](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) (probably not in the Update) in order to start its execution. Otherwise it's only a method call:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(wait(5));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call you coroutine by writing "StartCoroutine( wait )". You should put something before and after the yield command or else it is skipped. Try creating a boolean and disabling or enabling it before and after the yield, then you could adjust your code to check for that boolean and then run.